# error while running javain project in ububtu

Tags: java

i have this error when I run my project in ubuntu (sts,mysql) "***Several ports (8005, 8080) required by Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)."***

Comment: The error is quite explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to release ports (stop process running on particular port) on which you want to run your app.

This topic may be helpful:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/538208/how-to-check-opened-closed-port-on-my-computer

Answer (score 0):

The error message says clearly enough. Port 8005 or 8080 is in use by other process. You need to find which process is using it.

By checking this, please [refer](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/), you can find a tool that suitable for you.